# Generalized gluing lemma

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spheres

The **Gluing lemma** states that if you have two functions defined continuously over two closed sets such that the function is equal in the intersection, then the union of the functions is continuous.

My problem is that I want to glue together a countably infinite set of homotopies with fixed end points.

Can I assert that this gluing is continuous? If yes, what is a simple proof of this fact?

To give context, I was trying to simplify a proof of the [simple connectedness of the sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284809/fixing-this-proof-of-the-simple-connectedness-of-the-n-sphere). For the simplification to go through, I have to glue together these homotopies defined over a numerable set of segments of a path.

Comment: You can replace a finite family of closed set by a locally finite family of closed subsets to apply the glueing procedure, do you see why?
That should be sufficient.

Comment: @A.Rod what if the closed sets accumulate?

Comment: You mean in general or in your particular problem?
On your particular problem it does not matter because you want to avoid only 1 point in the interior of the disc, and the preimage of the point can meet only finitely many open intervals of $\gamma^{-1}(D^\circ)$ in $I$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104809/gluing-lemma-for-closed-sets-infinite-cover-counter-example?rq=1
seems relevant

Comment: @A.Rod I dont see that so Clear. What if the path crosses the Point infinitely many times? What's to stop him from doing so?

Comment: I'm not saying that the path cannot cross it infintely many times, after all the path can very well be sationary for some time.
What i'm saying is that your $\gamma^{-1}(D^\circ)$ is a countable union of disjoint open intervals say $J_n$ in $I$, and that $\gamma^{-1}(x_0)$ (where $x_0$ is the point in $D^\circ$ you want to avoid) is a compact subset of $I$ thus it can meet only fintely many of the $J_n$'s.

Comment: In other words you only have to homotope out your $\gamma$ in finitely many intervals $J_k$, for the other $J_\ell$, $\gamma_{|J_\ell}$ crosses $D^\circ$ but avoids $x_0$, which is the whole point of your construction anyway.
Is that clearer?

Comment: @A.Rod thanks! I am still confused because I do not see why the preimage of $x_0$ has to be compact

Comment: It is a closed subset of $I$.